# IMAP and Gmail: How to exclude address from Search

Tags: php, gmail, imap

I'm currently obtaining results with PHP and it's `imap_open` instruction but i have problems with the IMAP Instructions used in `imap_search` when i want to exclude an address.

When i use `imap_search($inbox, "FROM siidte_error@sii.cl")` i get the message i want to exclude (it exists) but i can't get the correct method of obtaining the rest of emails excluding it.

When i search `imap_search($inbox, "")` i get all the mails in the `$inbox` folder including the one i want to exclude (all of them are from distinct addresses).

I used `NOT FROM` and `FROM !siidte_error@sii.cl` but i got no emails as result.

Is there any method of getting results? How could it be done? I forgot to mention that i'm using GMail and i get the message just adding exclamation mark before the address, but it didn't work.

Thanks guys. I hope i've well related my issue.